# comparar dos columnas en una misma tabla y con base al resultado obtener los datos de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Soy relativamente nuevo en mysql y me ha parecido muy interesante pero me encuentro estancado en la realización de un consulta.

Tengo dos tablas en particular, dentro de la **`TABLA1`** existen dos columnas que requiero comparar y que dependiendo de su resultado me permita obtener la información de una columna de la **`TABLA2`** para registrarla en una columna de la **`TABLA1`** cuando se requiera.

Disculpen mi ignorancia y mi inexperiencia pero necesito comparar la columna (`Nombre_licencia_unica`) y la columna (`Id_equipo`) de la **`TABLA1`** para saber cual es el nombre del software (`Nombre_licencia_unica`) que está vinculado a un computador (`Id_equipo`):

1. Si un computador (`Id_equipo`) no tiene vinculado algún software (`Nombre_licencia_unica`) se debería mostrar disponible.
2. Si un computador (`Id_equipo`) tiene vinculado solo un software (`Nombre_licencia_unica`) por ejemplo *`Microsoft windows`* no se debería mostrar disponible para *`Microsoft windows`*, pero si disponible para otro software (`Nombre_licencia_unica`) por ejemplo *`Microsoft Office`*.
3. Si un computador (`Id_equipo`) tiene vinculado software (`Nombre_licencia_unica`) por ejemplo *`Microsoft windows`* y *`Microsoft Office`* no se debería mostrar disponible.

TABLA1:

```
CREATE TABLE LICENCIAS_UNICAS
(
Id_licencia_unica INT,
Nombre_licencia_unica VARCHAR (25),
Version_licencia_unica VARCHAR (25),
Fecha_de_adquisicion_licencia_unica DATE,
Precio_de_adquisicion_licencia_unica VARCHAR (20),
Dado_de_baja_licencia_unica VARCHAR (2),
Fecha_de_baja_licencia_unica DATE,
Estado_licencia_unica VARCHAR (8),
Id_equipo INT
);
```

TABLA2:

```
CREATE TABLE EQUIPOS
(
Id_equipo INT,
Marca_equipo VARCHAR (20),
Nombre_de_equipo VARCHAR (30),
Fecha_de_adquisicion_equipo DATE,
Precio_de_adquisicion_equipo VARCHAR (20),
Dado_de_baja_equipo VARCHAR (2),
Fecha_de_baja_equipo DATE);
```

LLAVES:

```
ALTER TABLE LICENCIAS_UNICAS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_LICENCIAS_UNICAS PRIMARY KEY (Id_licencia_unica);
ALTER TABLE LICENCIAS_UNICAS ADD FOREIGN KEY (Id_equipo) REFERENCES EQUIPOS (Id_equipo);
ALTER TABLE EQUIPOS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_EQUIPOS PRIMARY KEY (Id_equipo);

ALTER TABLE LICENCIAS_UNICAS MODIFY Id_licencia_unica INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE EQUIPOS MODIFY Id_equipo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

INSERT INTO licencias_unicas (Nombre_licencia_unica, Version_licencia_unica, Fecha_de_adquisicion_licencia_unica, Precio_de_adquisicion_licencia_unica, Dado_de_baja_licencia_unica, Estado_licencia_unica) VALUES ('Microsoft Windows', '10 Pro', '2021-04-17', '450.000', 'No', 'Activo'), ('Microsoft Windows', '10 Pro', '2021-04-17', '450.000', 'No', 'Activo'), ('Microsoft Office', '10 Pro', '2021-04-17', '750.000', 'No', 'Activo'), ('Microsoft Office', '10 Pro', '2021-04-17', '750.000', 'No', 'Activo');
INSERT INTO equipos (Marca_equipo, Nombre_de_equipo, Fecha_de_adquisicion_equipo, Precio_de_adquisicion_equipo, Dado_de_baja_equipo) VALUES ('Lenovo', 'PC007', '2021-04-17', '600.000', 'No'), ('Sony', 'PC008', '2021-04-17', '600.000', 'No'), ('Samsung', 'PC009', '2021-04-17', '600.000', 'No');
```

Espero haber sido lo necesariamente claro y si no les pido disculpas ya que es mi primer pregunta después de haber agotado mi búsqueda por internet.

Finalmente agradecerles si me pueden brindar esta ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Edité tu pregunta porque, sin formato de código, era prácticamente ilegible. Te invito a observar cómo se le da formato, además de cuidar tu ortografía. En el editor encontrarás un par de botones con la documentación del sabor de _markdown_ que utilizamos por aquí.

Comment: Los scripts que proporcionas tienen errores. Tus probabilidades de encontrar ayuda mejoran si incluyes un script funcional para crear el esquema. Por otro lado, las filas que insertas en la tabla `licencias_unicas`, tienen todas `null` en el `id_equipo`. ¿Eso es intencional?

Comment: jachguate gracias por responder y por ayudarme con el formato, es intencional que esten en null

Answer (score 0):

Tu primera consulta la resolvería así:

```
SELECT *,'Disponible' Disponibilidad
  FROM EQUIPOS
  WHERE Id_equipo NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Id_equipo
      FROM LICENCIAS_UNICAS
      WHERE Id_equipo IS NOT NULL
  );
```

La segunda entiendo que es igual a la tercera, sería algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,'Disponible' Disponibilidad
      FROM EQUIPOS,(
        SELECT DISTINCT Nombre_licencia_unica,
          Version_licencia_unica
          FROM LICENCIAS_UNICAS  
      ) c1  
  ) c2 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Id_equipo,Nombre_licencia_unica,
      Version_licencia_unica FROM EQUIPOS 
      JOIN LICENCIAS_UNICAS USING(Id_equipo)  
  ) c3 USING(Id_equipo,Nombre_licencia_unica,
      Version_licencia_unica)
  WHERE c3.Id_equipo IS NULL
  ORDER BY c2.Id_equipo;
```

He hecho un producto cartesiano de todos los equipos con todo el software y me he quedado únicamente con aquellas combinaciones que no se han dado en la realidad. Ahora que lo pienso, igual habría que quitar de las consultas el campo `Version_licencia_unica` porque tampoco tendría mucho sentido tener instaladas varias versiones del mismo software en el mismo equipo.

Para hacer las pruebas he utilizado este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE EQUIPOS (
  Id_equipo int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Marca_equipo varchar(20),
  Nombre_de_equipo varchar(30),
  Fecha_de_adquisicion_equipo date,
  Precio_de_adquisicion_equipo varchar(20),
  Dado_de_baja_equipo varchar(2),
  Fecha_de_baja_equipo date
);

CREATE TABLE LICENCIAS_UNICAS (
  Id_licencia_unica int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Id_equipo int,
  Nombre_licencia_unica varchar(25),
  Version_licencia_unica varchar(25),
  Fecha_de_adquisicion_licencia_unica date,
  Precio_de_adquisicion_licencia_unica varchar(20),
  Dado_de_baja_licencia_unica varchar(2),
  Fecha_de_baja_licencia_unica date,
  Estado_licencia_unica varchar(8),
  FOREIGN KEY (Id_equipo) REFERENCES EQUIPOS (Id_equipo)
);
```

He sustituido algunos `NULL` por datos de prueba y así comprobar que obtenía los resultados esperados:

```
INSERT INTO EQUIPOS (Marca_equipo, Nombre_de_equipo, Fecha_de_adquisicion_equipo,
  Precio_de_adquisicion_equipo, Dado_de_baja_equipo)
  VALUES ('Lenovo', 'PC007', '2021-04-17', '600.000', 'No'),
  ('Sony', 'PC008', '2021-04-17', '600.000', 'No'),
  ('Samsung', 'PC009', '2021-04-17', '600.000', 'No');
INSERT INTO LICENCIAS_UNICAS (Id_equipo,Nombre_licencia_unica, Version_licencia_unica,
  Fecha_de_adquisicion_licencia_unica, Precio_de_adquisicion_licencia_unica,
  Dado_de_baja_licencia_unica, Estado_licencia_unica)
  VALUES (1,'Microsoft Windows', '10 Pro', '2021-04-17', '450.000', 'No', 'Activo'),
  (2,'Microsoft Windows', '10 Pro', '2021-04-17', '450.000', 'No', 'Activo'),
  (1,'Microsoft Office', '10 Pro', '2021-04-17', '750.000', 'No', 'Activo'),
  (NULL,'Microsoft Office', '10 Pro', '2021-04-17', '750.000', 'No', 'Activo');
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios